# Laptop Powers On Only When the Frame is Tweaked

Tags: laptop, shutdown

I have a laptop that will power on and then immediately shutdown unless I prop something thin under the bottom left corner of the frame and depress the center near the mouse pad. Once it boots it will continue to run until I remove the prop. Any ideas as to what is going on? I have a sneaking suspicion its a bad connection on the motherboard that reconnects under the above conditions.

Comment: ... how did you find out this solution ?! its awesome ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities that I can foresee:

- It could be that the case is *shorting*, which means that there is an electrically-conducting path, usually some kind of metal, from the power source (battery or A/C adapter or PSU) into the outer case chassis. In this situation the electricity will take the shortest path to "ground" (through your body if you're holding it, or through the table it's on), which trips the breaker in the PSU and shuts down the unit. Propping up the corner and pressing on the center could be interrupting the conductive path by moving the conductor away from the place where it's conducting, or moving the conducting material away from the conductor.
- You could be right that it's a loose cable/connection, too, though this would be most likely to be fixed by pressing on the center of the laptop than by the "corner prop" thing (unless the laptop does not sit perfectly level on the table without the prop).

Unfortunately you will probably need to take apart the laptop to figure it out. "Benching" the laptop by putting the motherboard+PSU+CPU+RAM on a table and turning it on, *without* pressing down on anything, should indicate whether there is a case short: without a case to short to, it would boot up fine.

If it's a loose cable, you will probably find the loose cable simply by taking it apart, and removing and re-attaching all the cables. If any of them feel very loose when you re-plug them, that's likely your culprit, and you can test it by using some tape to more tightly secure the connection and see if it improves the system stability. Or, better yet, replace the loose cable with a new one.

Difficult to be sure what this is without playing around with it, but don't worry about shorting the case, the amperage put out by a laptop should not be hazardous to you.

Comment: I have taken the whole thing apart and then reassembled which seemed to solve the problem for a few boots but its back again. Benching the hardware is a good next step. +1

Comment: @Scandalist When you dissasembled it , did you fix up the thermals everywhere too? The primary likelyhood is a short and connections, but what if it is the connection to the heat removal stuff (thermal interfaces)?  Just How immediate was the shutdown?